# 403 Issue with twitter API v2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, social-media

Recently I was learning about APIs and tried learning about the Twitter one.

I authenticated my App, and even regenerated my API and the API key, yet it still doesn't seem to work.

I looked up on YouTube and most of them say that I have to upgrade it to elevated access, yet that option doesn't appear on my developer portal. At this point I'm basically lost, I looked up that Twitter wanted to get right of third party users, but I don't know if that means that the API doesn't work anymore. Regardless, I'm not giving up until I get a concrete answer.

Here is my code.

```
import tweepy

keys = open('keys.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
TwitterAPI = keys[0]
TwitterAPIKey_secret = keys[1]
TwitterAccesstoken = keys[2]
TwitterAccesstokensecret = keys[3]

Authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TwitterAPI, TwitterAPIKey_secret)
Authenticator.set_access_token(TwitterAccesstoken, TwitterAccesstokensecret)

Api = tweepy.API(Authenticator)

Api.update_status('test')
```

Comment: You seems to don't have permission to do that, because of Elon Musk's actions ...

Comment: Is it really a twitter Policy?

Comment: Don't tag users to beg for help. This isn't a social media site (and that would be rude anyway). I read your post. I don't have an answer. If I did I'd have told you so.

Comment: Yes, it could be. Now Twitter API became premium. You should check first for what you can do thanks to the free access